# How to resolve VBA Error "Unable to get the selected property of the range class "

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and just started learning on my own.
When I try to run my program...

```
Sub cpy()
    range("k1:k12").Select
    Selection.copy
    Application.Goto Worksheets("Sheet1").range("m4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

... I get the following error: `Unable to get the selected property of the range class`.
So I tried to run the erroring line separately:

```
Sub cck()
    Application.Goto Worksheets("Sheet1").range("m4").Value
End Sub
```

It shows the following error: `Run-time error '1004': Reference isn't valid`.

The Excel file is new, contains 3 sheets and the sheet names are not altered. I tried to run the above codes on Sheet3.

Comment: Hi, From your code what I understood is that you are trying to paste the copied value (k1 to k12) to M4 and its sub sequence Column. If so use  `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` . Hope it will help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Application.Goto` itself already selects, so tacking on `Select` at the end like that doesn't make sense. `Application.Goto` performs an action -- it goes to a certain range, it doesn't *return* a range which you need to select.

In any event, the best way to resolve the error is to eliminate `Select` from your code. It is seldom needed. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4996248).

Even though that linked question is explicitly about `Select`, it applies to `Application.Goto` as well. Both `Select` and `Goto` lead to spaghetti code. A classic essay that all programmers should read at least once is [Go To Statement Considered Harmful](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Estorm/teaching/reader/Dijkstra68.pdf) by Dijkstra. He didn't have `Application.Goto` in mind of course, but it nevertheless applies.

Answer (score 0):

### Three Ways of Copying a Range

- [`Range.Copy method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy), [`Range.PasteSpecial method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial), [`Application.CutCopyMode property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.cutcopymode)
- At this stage, step-by-step is the way to go: use `Option Explicit`, declare variables (e.g. `Dim wb As Workbook`), and create references to (`Set`) all objects (e.g. `Set ws = ThisWorkbook`).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub copyRangeCopy()
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("K1:K12")
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range("M4")
    
    ' Copy (values, formulas, formats)
    srg.Copy dCell
    
    ' Copy by assignment (values only, but very fast)
    'dCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count) = srg.Value
    
    ' Copy/PasteSpecial (many options, but the destination sheet becomes active)
    'srg.Copy
    'dCell.PasteSpecial ' many options
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub
```